# git: mirror all repositories that exist on a remote git server?

Tags: git, mirror

I am in the process of setting up a git server that mirrors all existing and future repositories that exist on our primary git server. Since I can't statically list all repositories to mirror I am wondering the best way to retrieve this list and perform 'git clone --mirror' on each.

Alternatively a push method that keeps the mirror in sync would be fine too. What are others doing? I'm new to git (sys admin).

Answer (score 1):

How about simply:

```
ssh theservername ls /some/path/under/which/the/repos/live/
```

Comment: This was my initial thought, just making sure I'm not missing a Git feature or push method that would be better. Thank you very much.